# Converting df into ts object and decompose in 15 minute intervals in R

Tags: r, time-series

I know there has been a lot on this topic already but I can't seem to get what I want working.
I've read:

[how to convert data frame into time series in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046311/how-to-convert-data-frame-into-time-series-in-r)

[Convert data frame with date column to timeseries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732461/convert-data-frame-with-date-column-to-timeseries)

As well as several others but can't get it to work.

I have the following `df`

```
df <- data.frame(CloseTime = c("2017-09-13 19:15:00","2017-09-13 19:30:00","2017-09-13 19:45:00","2017-09-13 20:00:00","2017-09-13 20:15:00"),
             OpenPice = c(271.23,269.50,269.82,269.10,269.50),
             HightPrice = c(271.23,269.50,269.82,269.10,269.50),
             LowPrice = c(271.23,269.50,269.82,269.10,269.50),
             ClosePrice = c(271.23,269.50,269.82,269.10,269.50))
```

I'd like to convert it into a `ts`object, with 15-minute intervals and decompose the time series.

I also read that the zoo package allows you to decompose specific multiple intervals i.e. 15 mins, 1h, 1 day?

Can someone please help. How can I convert this into a ts object and decompose my ts object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the reproducibility purpose, another toy-example with longer period of time.

```
df <- 
  data.frame(
    CloseTime = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-09-13 19:15:00"),as.POSIXct("2018-10-20 21:45:00"),by="15 mins"),
    ClosePrice1 = cumsum(rnorm(38603)),
    ClosePrice2 = cumsum(rnorm(38603)),
    ClosePrice3 = cumsum(rnorm(38603))
  )
```

I found it much better to aggregate time series into different intervals using dplyr and [lubridate::floor_date](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.5.6/topics/round_date?). Instead of `mean`, one can summarise using `min`, `max`, `first`, `last`. I would recommend stay around the tidyr to keep code readable. Below example converting into 30minutes interval.

```
library(lubridate); library(dplyr); library(magrittr)
df30m <-
  df %>%
  group_by( CloseTime = floor_date( CloseTime, "30 mins")) %>%
  summarize_all(mean)
```

Data.frame can be converted to timeseries object such as `zoo` and than to `ts` for decomposing purposes.

```
library(zoo)
df30m_zoo <- zoo( df30m[-1], order.by = df30m$CloseTime )
df30m_ts  <- ts(df30m_zoo, start=1, frequency = 2 * pi)

df30m_decomposed <- decompose(df30m_ts)
```

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm. A quick question, my `seasonal` component contains `NA` values at the beginning and the end of my series. Why is that?

Comment: Probably because of filtering function (MA). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194922/na-results-in-decomposition-of-additive-time-series-in-r

Answer (score 1):

The points are already 15 minutes apart so assuming that you want a period of 1 day this will convert it.  There are 24 * 60 * 60 seconds in a day (which s the period) but you can change the denominator to the number of seconds in a period get a different period.  You will need at least two periods of data to decompose it.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(df)
time(z) <- (as.numeric(time(z)) - as.numeric(start(z))) / (24 * 60 * 60)
as.ts(z)
```

giving:

```
Time Series:
Start = c(0, 1) 
End = c(0, 5) 
Frequency = 96 
           OpenPice HightPrice LowPrice ClosePrice
0.00000000   271.23     271.23   271.23     271.23
0.01041667   269.50     269.50   269.50     269.50
0.02083333   269.82     269.82   269.82     269.82
0.03125000   269.10     269.10   269.10     269.10
0.04166667   269.50     269.50   269.50     269.50
```

Alhtough not asked for in the question, in another answer the data was converted to 30 minutes.   That could readily be done like this:

```
library(xts) # also loads zoo

z <- read.zoo(df)
to.minutes30(z)
```

Comment: Thanks, if I use `decompose` I'm getting error `Error in decompose(z) : time series has no or less than 2 periods`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have changed it to use a period of one day but if you have less than 2 days of data change it to a smaller period as described.  You must have at least 2 periods in your data to decompose it.